# Auto complete milestone when reach violation

Tags: apex, trigger, casemilestone

Is there a way to automatically mark the milestone as completed when it reach violation? I tried to create an apex trigger (after update) on case object that will update the caseMilestone completion date to system.now() if the custom field named 'Close_Milestone__c' on case object populated as true.. this field is updated from milestone action field update

[image]

the action field update is working fine, the field is updated to true. But it`s not triggering the apex trigger at all. Here`s some snippet.

```
if (objCase.Close_Milestone__c && objCase.Close_Milestone__c != objPreviousCase.Close_Milestone__c) {
                setCaseId.add(objCase.Id);
                isCloseMilestone = true;
            }

if (isCloseMilestone) {
            List<CaseMilestone> cmsToUpdate = [select Id, completionDate
            from CaseMilestone cm
            where caseId in :setCaseId and completionDate = null limit 1];
            if (cmsToUpdate.isEmpty() == false){
                for (CaseMilestone cm : cmsToUpdate){
                    cm.completionDate = system.now();
                }
                update cmsToUpdate;
            }
        }
```

If I try to trigger it manually by updating the Close_Milestone__c field to true from UI, the apex trigger is triggered and milestone is completed.

Comment: it is possible that when milestone gets checked as violated it won't trigger any updates. Did you try approach this similarly with flow or process builder?

Comment: Yes, I tried process builder, not triggered also.. so, milestone action field update wont trigger any process and this is expected? or mine is broken.. the requirement is to stop the SLA when it reach violation, and then continue to the next milestone order

Comment: It seems like a known issue:  https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SU70AAG, and here is a workaround: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A7bVpSAJ

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling Change Data Capture on Case and subscribing in the trigger to it:

```
trigger CaseChangeEventTrigger on CaseChangeEvent (after insert) {
    //this code should trigger
}
```